# Can´t figure out the problem with MYSQL query

Tags: mysql

Hey Guys I have this query

```
SELECT SUM(body), SUM(mice), SUM(sety) FROM
(
  SELECT sum(body1) as body, sum(mice1) as mice, sum(sety1) as sety from utkani where hrac1 in(select hrac1 from skupina where id=66) 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT sum(body2) as body, sum(mice2) as mice, sum(sety2) as sety from utkani where hrac2 in(select hrac1 from skupina where id=66) 
)
```

and I am getting error:

```
#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias
```

Can you help me with this please?

Comment: please like the answer at least if you are satisfied by the effort of the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you missed adding an alias to the virtual table you are querying

```
SELECT SUM(body), SUM(mice), SUM(sety) FROM
(
  SELECT sum(body1) as body, sum(mice1) as mice, sum(sety1) as sety from utkani where hrac1 in(select hrac1 from skupina where id=66) 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT sum(body2) as body, sum(mice2) as mice, sum(sety2) as sety from utkani where hrac2 in(select hrac1 from skupina where id=66) 
) as temp
```

Comment: Thank you, it´s working :)

Answer (score 1):

A deivd table is that what youi have afuter the first `FROM` clause

As it is a tbale, it must a  name like utkani  but as you see a t1 is enough

```
SELECT SUM(body), SUM(mice), SUM(sety) FROM
(
  SELECT sum(body1) as body, sum(mice1) as mice, sum(sety1) as sety from utkani where hrac1 in(select hrac1 from skupina where id=66) 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT sum(body2) as body, sum(mice2) as mice, sum(sety2) as sety from utkani where hrac2 in(select hrac1 from skupina where id=66) 
) t1
```

Comment: Thank you, it´s working :)